# Browser behavior for multiple cookies with same name/path

Tags: cookies

I'm interested in the behavior of various browsers when there are multiple cookies with the same name and path which are valid for the current domain. E.g. the browser has stored these two cookies:

```
key=value; path=/; domain=foo.bar.baz
key=value; path=/; domain=bar.baz
```

What will be the content of the `Cookie` header when the user visits `foo.bar.baz`?

[RFC 2965](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt) has this to say about the issue:

> If multiple cookies satisfy the criteria above, they are ordered in
>      the Cookie header such that those with more specific Path attributes
>      precede those with less specific.  Ordering with respect to other
>      attributes (e.g., Domain) is unspecified.

(which is IMO a very weird design choice, but that is what we have). I suppose server-side frameworks use the first value, beacause that is at least sometimes more specific (I checked PHP and it indeed does so).

What I would like to know is the behavior of the major browsers: which cookie would they send first? (In other words, how much can I rely on my application getting the "correct", more specific value?)

Comment: I think that regardless of the behaviour of any browser at the moment you can't rely on such an emperical answer since the standard says "unspecified" and any browser/any version can change this behaviour anytime...

Comment: It's not really about relying, more about defending against it... this could result in two sites on the same parent domain altering each other's behavior in unpredictable ways. (That's how I found out about it actually, both sites used a PHPSESSID cookie and people got inexplicably logged out.)

Comment: not sure that I understand... you want to defend against "undefined behaviour" (standard-wise) based on an emperical answer which can become obsolete/incomplete as soon as a new browser patch or version comes up ? How would you defend against that and how would you keep your defense up2date ?

Comment: the easiest defense from my POV is to not use PHPSESSID on the main domain `bar.baz` - the rest will work fine since according to the standard there no "fallback" in that so the cookie stays on its own subdomain... perhaps there are even some misconfigured PHP scripts running on a subdomain which explicitly set their cookie on the main domain ?

Comment: try so learn interesting comments with the Firefox plugin YSlow (Yahoo Slow) where there are tons of advices, and one of them should answer to your question (look for "static domain names").

Answer (score 4):

As per comments above:

The easiest defense against this obviously "undefined behaviour (standard-wise)" from my POV is to not use `PHPSESSID` on the main domain `bar.baz` but instead on `www.bar.baz` - the subdomains will work fine since according to the standard there is no "fallback" in that case so the cookie stays on its own subdomain.

One possible problem needs to be checked:

PHP scripts running on a subdomain can be configured explicitly to set their cookie on the main domain... IF that is the case (code looks similar to `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'bar.baz');`) then you need to change this config to "standard" (by removing the code shown) which means that a script on a subdomain should only set cookies on its own subdomain.

**EDIT - as per comments:**

IF you don't have any control over some other subdomain then the *"ultimate defense"* is to rename your `PHPSESSID` cookie to something really unique (like a GUID with `PHPSESSID` as prefix) either by [calling `session_name()` BEFORE `session_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php)  OR by [setting it in the config](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name) - this way you circumvent the whole problem regardless of subdomains/browser versions etc.

Comment: The problem is that even if I make sure cookies are always set on `www.bar.baz` (which I do anyway, setting cookies on `bar.baz` would have several drawbacks, from increased image/script request size to session hijacking vulnerabilities), a script on `someothersite.bar.baz` (which might be less well maintained, or not under my control) can still interfere with my login process. I want to know how widespread such a problem could be.

Comment: @Tgr I undestand the problem... please see my EDIT for a solution that is independent of browsers/versions and can be implemented in a way that even misbehaving subdomains won't create a problem for your subdomain... HTH

Comment: Changing the name of the session cookie is certainly a good idea, but there are many cookies which could possibly conflict, some with fixed name (such as the Google Analytics tracking cookies). What I would like to know is on what percentage of browsers could this be a problem.