# Why cookies behavior differ between Firefox and Chromium?

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, chromium

I'm using the [docCookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie) object to set cookies on [this](https://github.com/lucio-martinez/Game-Window) application.

The function that I'm testing is this one:

```
displayWelcomeMessage = function(idElement){
    var cookieName = 'username';

    alert(docCookies.getItem(cookieName)); // NULL when cookie not set

    var defaultName = "SweetAnon",
        daysToExpire = 1,
        username = docCookies.getItem(cookieName);

    // Check if cookie was already set (user "logged")
    if (username != null && username.trim() != "") {
        displayUsername(idElement, username);
    } else {
        username = prompt("If you enter your name\nI'll try to remember you :)");
        if (username != null && username.trim() != "") {
            docCookies.setItem(cookieName, username, daysToExpire);
            displayUsername(idElement, username);
        } else {
            displayUsername(idElement, defaultName);
        }
    }
    alert(docCookies.getItem(cookieName)); // Username or 'SweetAnon'
};
```

Here are two alerts and they print different results between Firefox v28 and Chromium v33.0.1750.152. If I enter `foobar` as `username` I get this results:

- Firefox prints `null` and then `foobar`.
- Chromium it prints `null` and then `null` again.

I consider the Firefox behavior correct. But what should I do to make it work on Chromium?

Comment: Storing the user name in the cookies is a bad idea for security reasons, assuming that the user logs into your site with a password.

Comment: I'm handling 1 string that won't store sensitive data. I want to understand who does cookies work cross-browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser behavior for multiple cookies with same name/path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997871/browser-behavior-for-multiple-cookies-with-same-name-path)

Comment: The other post is not related with this issue. I don't see any solution there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to assign the cookie value to an object rather than a variable:

```
displayWelcomeMessage = function(idElement)
  {
  var cookieName = 'username',
      defaultName = "SweetAnon",
      daysToExpire = 1;

  /* assign username as a property of the current function */

  this.username = docCookies.getItem(cookieName);

  alert(docCookies.getItem(cookieName)); // NULL when cookie not set

  // Check if cookie was already set (user "logged")

  if (this.username != null && this.username.trim() != "")
      {
      displayUsername(idElement, this.username);
      } 

    else 
      {
      this.username = prompt("If you enter your name\nI'll try to remember you :)");

      if (this.username != null && this.username.trim() != "") 
        {
        docCookies.setItem(cookieName, this.username, daysToExpire);
        displayUsername(idElement, username);
        } 
      else 
        {
        displayUsername(idElement, defaultName);
        }
      }

  alert(docCookies.getItem(cookieName)); // Username or 'SweetAnon'
  };
```

**References**

- [Which design pattern(s) take advantage of JavaScript's hoisting behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597501/1113772)
- [Javascript Hoisting in Chrome And Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242399/1113772)
- [JavaScript Scope and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)
- [Conditionally Defining a Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Conditionally_defining_a_function)